# navController.navigate(fragmentAId) vs navController.navigate(action_fragmentA_to_fragmentB)?

Tags: android, navigation, fragment, android-jetpack

In navigation component of android what's different between just passing one fragment id to `navController.navigate()` with passing `action fragment a to fragment b` ?

Answer (score 0):

both would work the same and land you to the same view but with action id you get all the options you add to the Action in xml like animation sometime this is what you want it is all up to you